# Performance bottlenecks of Linux traffic shaping (tc)

Tags: linux, networking, performance, tc

I have an interesting problem.

We have a Linux server with Debian Stretch installed. The server has a single CPU E5-2680 v2 and Intel 82599ES 10G Dual Port NIC's. There are no other services (like HTTP and so on) running on it.

All seems good, until I enable traffic shaping. The shaping rules consist of `htb qdisc` on the `bond0` and `bond1` interface.

There is a three step hashing filter:

1. Four rule filter to select a large subnet. The rules look like this:

   ```
   protocol ip u32 ht 800:: match ip src 10.15.0.0/18 hashkey mask 0x0000ff00 at 12 link 1:
   ```
2. 60 or so rule tables to select a /24 out of that large subnet

   ```
   protocol ip u32 ht 1:10 match ip src 10.15.16.0/24 hashkey mask 0x000000ff at 12 link 100:
   ```
3. 256 rule tables to match the IP

   ```
   parent 1:0 prio 100 protocol ip u32 ht 100:20: match ip src 10.15.16.32 flowid 1:20    
   class add dev bond0 parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 24Gbit ceil 24Gbit burst 4096k cburst 256k
   class add dev bond0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 102400Kbit  burst 4096k cburst 256k    
   qdisc add dev bond0 parent 1:20 pfifo_fast
   ```

Now, when I enable these rules, I get at most around 10Gbps total traffic and then ping starts to go up to 100ms or more. However, during that time, the CPU load is almost none - `uptime` shows a load of 0.07 and each CPU core is only about 5% utilized. `ping` instantly becomes OK once I clear the shaping rules.

Previously I used `sfq` instead of `pfifo_fast`, and that did result in a large CPU load. I then switched to red, which produced a bit better results with no CPU load, then I switched to `pfifo_fast` which produces almost the same results as red.

- What other bottleneck could be there?
- Has anyone tried using Linux traffic shaper for a network that's over 10gbps?

Comment: Please add the brand and model of your NICs.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added

Comment: FWIW, I had similar performance problems using `tc` to emulate a WAN.  I don't remember the exact details as it was a few years ago, but I was only using 100baseT ethernet as that was about the bandwidth on the WAN connection I was emulating, so I was hoping I could just use `tc` to add latency.  And I still had performance problems similar to what you're describing when I started increasing the simulated latency, including severe bandwidth limitations well beneath what the underlying hardware  supported without `tc` shaping.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and haven't found a solution.

One clarification, please, you say, "get at most around 10Gbps".  What would you expect on a 10Gbps NIC?  Should that be 10Mbps?  1Gbps?